# Don't Automatically Scrolls Message in Swift3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I used pod "JSQMessagesViewController" in my project.
But the received messages are not automatically scrolls in my UI.
How to solve this problem?. Have anyone this experience?
Please help me.

Comment: It has property automaticallyScrollsToMostRecentMessage, did you set this to YES?

Comment: I set
automaticallyScrollsToMostRecentMessage = true
but can't work. @iOS_devloper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is make sure that you have this line in your code 
`automaticallyScrollsToMostRecentMessage = true`

In the swift example they have it in the `viewDidLoad` method.

You also may want to call `finishReceivingMessage()` at the end of your "fetchMessages" method this is similar to `collectionView.reloadData()` for the `JSQMessagesViewController`

Hope that helps.